# Why no AutoResetEventSlim in BCL?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, c#-4.0, base-class-library

Why isn't there an `AutoResetEventSlim` class in BCL?

Can it be simulated using `ManualResetEventSlim`?

Comment: `AutoResetEventSlim` can be simulated using `SemaphoreSlim`.

Comment: @svick: It cannot. I spent two days debugging it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`ManualResetEvent` and `ManualResetEventSlim` both are designed so that they remained signaled after calling.  This is typically for a very different scenario than `AutoResetEvent`.

`AutoResetEvent` immediately returns to the unsignaled state after usage, which is typically used for a different set of scenarios.  From AutoResetEvents documentation:

> Typically, you use this class when threads need exclusive access to a resource.

`ManualResetEvent` (and `Slim`) are typically used, however, for a scenario where:

> this communication concerns a task which one thread must complete before other threads can proceed.

Since `AutoResetEvent` is most commonly used in scenarios where there are multiple threads sharing a resource, wait times typically would not be extremely short.  `ManualResetEventSlim`, however, is really only intended when you know, in advance, the wait time is very short.  If your wait time is not going to be very short, then you should use `ManualResetEvent` instead.  See the documentation on the [difference between MRE and MRES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hbefs30.aspx) for details.

When your wait times are longer (which would be the normal scenario with `AutoResetEvent`), the "slim" version is actually worse, as it reverts to using a wait handle.

Comment: I don't think the different typical use cases say anything about expected wait times at all. In fact, I'd expect less of a wait for "multiple threads sharing the same resource" than for "one thread must complete before other threads can proceed".

Answer (score 28):

I was bugged by this fact as well.
However, it appears that you can simulate an `AutoResetEvent(Slim)` using a simple [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim) with a special configuration:

```
SemaphoreSlim Lock = new SemaphoreSlim( 1, 1 );
```

In [the constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim.-ctor#System_Threading_SemaphoreSlim__ctor_System_Int32_System_Int32_), the first parameter defines the initial state of the semaphore: `1` means that one thread may enter, `0` that the semaphore has to be released first. So `new AutoResetEvent( true )` translates to `new SemaphoreSlim( 1, 1 )` and `new AutoResetEvent( false )` translates to `new SemaphoreSlim( 0, 1 )` respectively.

The second parameter defines the maximum number of threads that may enter the semaphore concurrently. Setting it to `1` lets it behave like an `AutoResetEvent`.

One other nice thing about the `SemaphoreSlim` is that with the new `async`/`await` pattern in 4.5 the class has received a [`.WaitAsync()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim.waitasync) which can be awaited. So there is no need to manually create an awaitable wait primitive in this case any more.

Hope this helps.

Comment: One complication when using the `SemaphoreSlim` as a stand-in for `AutoResetEvent`: trying to release when already at maximum count will throw a `SemaphoreFullException`, unlike setting the event when already set.

Answer (score 1):

To quote Microsoft's Josh Phillips ([original here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9ce62320-68fe-4d07-8576-f30a0325a68c/when-to-use-manualreseteventslim?forum=parallelextensions)):

> As for AutoResetEventSlim.. is there a scenario for which you need it?
> Truth be told, **creating an AutoResetEvent is quite difficult and the
> use cases are very limited so we prioritized our efforts elsewhere**.
> If there's a real need for you to have one, I'd love to hear it so we
> could consider creating one!

To expand on the comment: you can just use a manual event and make sure to always reset it after waiting.

If that small delay between waiting and resetting is causing problems, there's probably a fundamental issue somewhere anyway. For instance, if there are multiple consumers and you should only let one through, maybe an event isn't the right tool for the job and you should consider `SemaphoreSlim` or even just the raw `Monitor`.