# Is using IEnumerator is the best way to implement asynchronous while multithreading is seems to be slow?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I am trying to create some kind of framework that simplifies process of writing object interaction algorithm. (One object -- many clients(algorithms))

- For example I want to implement algorithm that do some very simple job and waits some condition meet in a loop:

  ```
  public void MakeVerySimpleJob() { }

  public void AsyncLoop()
  { // real algorithm can be more complex, but job is always very simple
      while (true)
      {
          MakeVerySimpleJob();
          WakeUpCondition = "As fast as u can!";
          JobComplete.Set();
          WakeUp.WaitOne();
      }
  }

  void main()
  {
      Thread MyThread = new Thread(AsyncLoop);
      MyThread.Start();

      var w = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch(); w.Start();
      for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
      {
          // waitin for thread
          JobComplete.WaitOne();
          // ok we did it
          WakeUpCondition = null;
          WakeUp.Set();
      }
      w.Stop();
  }

  AutoResetEvent JobComplete = new AutoResetEvent(false);
  AutoResetEvent WakeUp = new AutoResetEvent(false);
  ```

  Unfortunately it consumes about `500ms` to do 100000 simple jobs.
- Ok multithreading is not acceptable in my case, but I dont want to force users to write algorithms in this manner:

  ```
  // invoke it again and again
  public void PseudoAsyncLoop()
  {
      if (CurrentState == 1) 
      {
          MakeVerySimpleJob();
          CurrentState = 2;
          return;
      }
      else is (CurrentState == some_sate)
      {
      }
  }

  int CurrentState = 0;
  ```
- So i look at `Enumerators`. With Enumerators user can implement their own algorithm in traditional style:

  ```
  public IEnumerable<bool> PseudoAsyncLoop()
  {
      while (true)
      {
          MakeVerySimpleJob();
          WakeUpCondition = "As fast as u can!";
          yield return true;
      }
  }

  public string WakeUpCondition { get; private set; }

  void main()
  {
      var MyLoop = PseudoAsyncLoop();
      var LoopEnumerator = MyLoop.GetEnumerator();

      var w = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch(); w.Start();
      for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i ++)
      {
          LoopEnumerator.MoveNext();
          // ok we did it
          WakeUpCondition = null;
      }
      w.Stop();
  }
  ```

  Now it takes about `3ms`, great. But i think its something wrong with that all...

**My questions is:**

- **Am I in right direction?**
- **How does professional programmers solves that types of problems?**
- **May be there is some ways to optimize multithreaded version?**

Comment: Have you thought about writing your framework in a way that simply allows your users to use the parallel programming features that are already available in the .NET Framework?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460693.aspx

Comment: Could you describe in more detail what exactly are you trying to do any why? For example, in your code, both “threads” write to `WakeUpCondition`, but no one ever reads it, that doesn't make sense. Also, do both “threads” really have to wait on each other? Isn't one of the threads a “producer”, which could produce a few items before they are consumed by the other thread?

Comment: Also, what you're trying to do is very similar to the new `async`/`await`. Can you upgrade to C# 5.0?

Answer (score 1):

I don't completely understand what are you doing or why, but if this is actually representative of your code, then you can speed it up by using one of the `-Slim` synchronization primitives. [There is no `AutoResetEventSlim`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8215380/41071), but you can use `SemaphoreSlim` instead:

```
private readonly SemaphoreSlim JobComplete = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);
private readonly SemaphoreSlim WakeUp = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);

private void AsyncLoop()
{
    while (true)
    {
        MakeVerySimpleJob();
        WakeUpCondition = "As fast as u can!";
        JobComplete.Release();
        WakeUp.Wait();
    }
}

private void main()
{
    Thread MyThread = new Thread(AsyncLoop);
    MyThread.Start();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        JobComplete.Wait();
        WakeUpCondition = null;
        WakeUp.Release();
    }
}
```

This results in about 5.5× faster execution on my machine.